# What service restart first when we put 2 or more arguments (or in this same time)?

Tags: powershell

I need restart 2 services, but first vmicvss and next vss.

```
Get-Service -Name vmicvss, vss | Restart-Service
```

General services vss need vmicvss to run properly and I want know how exactly this code is execution. Is like:

```
Restart-Service vmicvss
Restart-Service vss
```

Or
in this same time or random moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Get-Service` and `Restart-Service`** apparently output / restart services in ***alphabetical* order when given an array of names via *parameter* `-Name`**.<sup>[1]</sup>

By contrast, **providing the names / service objects via the *pipeline* does honor the input order**:

```
# CAVEAT: Names passed to -Name are *sorted alphabetically*,
#         so 'vmicvss' is processed before 'vss', due to coming first
#         alphabetically.
Get-Service -Name vss, vmicvss | Restart-Service

# OK - with pipeline input, order is honored.
'vmicvss', 'vss' | Get-Service | Restart-Service

# OK (you don't need Get-Service in your scenario)
'vmicvss', 'vss' | Restart-Service
```

---

<sup>[1] As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.3; this problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8768).</sup>